# Transformation of a regular expression

Tags: regular-expressions

Let $a,b,c$ be regular expressions. Prove by transformation that 
    $$(a^*b^*+c)^* \equiv (a+ (b+c)^*)^*$$

I tried to start with the second term

$$(a + ((b+c)^*))^* = (a^*(b+c)^*)^* = (a^*(b^*c^*)^*)^*$$

but am stuck here. Can you please help me to go on?

Thanks!

[Edit:]

Transformation rules:

- $a + b = b + a$
- $(a + b) + c = a + ( b + c)$
- $\epsilon a = a = a \epsilon$
- $(a b) c = a (b c)$
- $a(b + c) = ab + bc$
- $(a + b)c = ac + bc$
- $\epsilon^* = \epsilon$
- $(a^*)^* = a^*$
- $(\epsilon + a)^* = a^*$
- $(a^*b^*)^* = (a+b)^*$
- $(ab)^*a = a(ab)^*$

Comment: What transformation rules are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add them. Now they're there.

Comment: Isn't that last transformation rule untrue? (The first one gives `abab...aba` and the second one gives `aab...ab`)

Comment: @dbaupp:  star * allows zero or more repetitions so the second one haven't start with a.

Comment: @Ehsan, yes, the first one allows `a`, `aba`, `ababa` etc; the second one allows `a`, `aab`, `aabab` etc. i.e. they are different regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:
$$(a + ((b+c)^*))^* = (a^*(b+c)^*)^*=(a+(b+c))^*$$
$$=((a+b)+c)^*=((a+b)^*c^*)^*=((a^*b^*)^*c^*)^*=(a^*b^*+c)^*$$

I used these rules:

- $(a^*)^* = a^*$
- $(a^*b^*)^* = (a+b)^*$
- $(a + b) + c = a + ( b + c)$

Comment: The step that introduces $(a^*(b^*c^*)^*)^*$ is unnecessary, and can be completely removed.

Comment: You are right, Thanks.